# What is the equlent libary avalable in flutter dart like Gson in java

Tags: dart, flutter, android, gson

Is there any library available to save object and restore it.
In android java we using Gson to do this but in flutter there is no Gson

Comment: I wrote a library which is able to parse JSON to an object automatically: https://github.com/gi097/json_parser/, serializing to JSON is not added.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen is it work if my JSON have multiple arrays and each array has multiple objects

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen is that possible to convert object to json using your libary?

Comment: I am not really sure but it should work @Midhilaj, you can always give it a try.

Comment: @Midhilaj no, only from json to an object instance.

Comment: @Midhilaj check this out. https://gist.github.com/kasperpeulen/d61029fc0bc6cd104602 this will only print out as json pretty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using this website and it saves my time 
no need to think just past the JSON code here then it will generate the prefect dart class code
https://app.quicktype.io/

Answer (score 8):

**A library like GSON won't be possible in Flutter,** since Flutter doesn't support code reflection. Reflection interferes with [tree shaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_shaking) which flutter needs to clean out unused code and give a compact app.

[more on the topic and alternatives here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#is-there-a-gsonjacksonmoshi-equivalent-in-flutter)

You can use [this site to convert your JSONs](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) to class and it prepares the toJson fromJson methods automatically.

Comment: But dart does support reflection? Via the dart:mirrors library

Comment: According to the link I shared, this is disabled in the flutter framework.

Answer (score 1):

You have for this the [built_value](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_value) package.

With that you can Serialize and Deserialize objects.

First you will need to declare the object:

```
part 'foo.g.dart'; 

abstract class Foo
    implements Built<Foo, FooBuilder>{
  static Serializer<Foo> get serializer => _$fooSerializer;

  String get fooValue;

  @nullable int get creationDate;

  Foo._();

  factory Foo([updates(FooBuilder b)]) = _$Foo;
}
```

All the object will have to follow this frame model:
- Being an abstract class implmenting `Built`
- Declaring a `static` `Serializer` getter value
- Declaring the `_()`
- Declaring a `factory`
- Declaring a `.part` at the top, so that we can generate a model file

I recommend to you copying the class and changing only the names and the model.

Then, if you want to serialize it, you have to create a `Serializer` class

```
import 'package:built_collection/built_collection.dart';
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';
import 'package:built_value/standard_json_plugin.dart';

part 'serializers.g.dart';

@SerializersFor(const [
  Foo // declare here all the classes to be serialized
])

Serializers serializers = _$serializers;

Serializers standardSerializers =
(serializers.toBuilder()
  ..add(CustomDateTimeSerializer()) // delcare here custom plugins
  ..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin())
  ).build();

}
```

As a bonus, I will post here a custom Serializer for time values:

```
/// Serializer for [DateTime] using Milliseconds instead of MicroSeconds
///
/// An exception will be thrown on attempt to serialize local DateTime
/// instances; you must use UTC.
class CustomDateTimeSerializer implements PrimitiveSerializer<DateTime> {
  final bool structured = false;
  @override
  final Iterable<Type> types = new BuiltList<Type>([DateTime]);
  @override
  final String wireName = 'DateTime';

  @override
  Object serialize(Serializers serializers, DateTime dateTime,
      {FullType specifiedType = FullType.unspecified}) {
    if (!dateTime.isUtc) {
      throw new ArgumentError.value(
          dateTime, 'dateTime', 'Must be in utc for serialization.');
    }

    return dateTime.microsecondsSinceEpoch / 1000;
  }

  @override
  DateTime deserialize(Serializers serializers, Object serialized,
      {FullType specifiedType = FullType.unspecified}) {
    final microsecondsSinceEpoch = serialized as int;
    return new DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(microsecondsSinceEpoch * 1000 * 1000,
        isUtc: true);
  }
}
```

After this, make sure to run the following in the terminal, on the root of your project folder:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner watch
```

The log will help you find errors that you have in your code.

Then, you will have the `.g` files for each model.

You can now serialize the object with:

```
import 'dart:convert' as json;

//...
var jsonEncoded = json.jsonEncode(standardSerializers.serializeWith(Foo.serializer, foo));
```

Bonus tip: this can also be used to have a builder for your object:

```
var foo = Foo((b) => b
   ..fooValue = "foo"
   ..creationDate = DateTime.now()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<void> saveLoginObj(LoginResponse obj) async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

try {
    String resp = json.encode(obj);
    await prefs.setString('apiToken',resp);

    // Get
    String token = prefs.getString('apiToken');
    var decoded = json.decode(token);
    LoginResponse loginResponse = LoginResponse.fromJson(decoded);

} on Exception catch (e) {
    print(e);
    throw Exception("Error on save token");
}
```

}

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).